# Uploading sitemap.xml

Tags: sitemap

I want to insert my own sitemap.xml in wordpress.

I don't want to use any Plugins Like Google XML Sitemaps, XML Sitemaps.

I want to get a output as a xml format like below.
[image]

But By using The Plugins I got the output as,
[image]

It's possible to get my sitemap.xml as a xml format in browser?

Insteed of auto generating, It's possible to upload my own sitemap.xml in wordpress?

Answer (score 1):

WordPress is set up in a way that mostly ignores existing files. If what you want is literally upload fixed `sitemap.xml` file you can just *do that* and upload it to the root of your site (using FTP, hosting control panel, or whatever). WordPress will just ignore it and it will be available at `example.com/sitemap.xml` as anything else would be.

Of course it won't update dynamically with your WP site. To do that without a plugin you would have to essentially write a plugin that does it yourself.